# How should I label a button which submits a form to start planning an event?

Tags: buttons, labeling

I have a simple form asking for this basic information: title, location, date, description, your name, invitees

When the button is clicked the event is created and invite emails go out to all the invitees.

What is the best label for this button? Create, Start, Invite, Plan, Go? Any suggestions and reasoning are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to limit it to one word? If the button is called `create event and send invites` then there is no ambiguity, so go with that. It's the main call-to-action on the page, it shouldn't be small and insignificant, nor should it require any thought by the user.

Answer (score 3):

I would say "Create" would be fine in this case. Essentially, the user is coming up with an event and adding in all of the details. Besides, create appeals to the creative aspect of the user's name, giving him/her a sense of control over an even that they plan.

"Invite" is too geared towards the invitations, instead of leading towards the general form.
"Go" is too simple, it does not make the feel